# Top-Panel Icons Become Empty

Tags: icons, mate, panel, menu, ubuntu-mate

The system is Ubuntu MATE version 18.04.2 using the "Familiar" panel layout.

I have installed a number of launchers in the Top Panel bar, but am having a problem with a couple of them.  Both of those are launchers for a sub-menu, rather than a particular app; as an example, one is the "Games" sub-menu.

What happens is that the icon remains normally visible and usually functional, but once in a while--and I cannot associate this behavior with any particular other operation--when one clicks on the icon, the dropdown is not the expected sub-menu but rather just an empty grey space.

This is a nuisance rather than a disaster, as I can simply use the "Remove From Panel" option and quickly re-add it back in.  But does anyone have an idea on why this is happening, and on whether there is a way to prevent it?

Comment: Do you have *locked* such items? Use right mouse click and select *Lock to Panel*.

Comment: Yes, they are locked to the panel.  In any event, the problem is not that they move or disappear, but that they don't bring up the sub-menu that they were pointed at.

Comment: There are no "steps to reproduce": I simply go along using my system and when, at some point, I want to play some game I click on the dropdown and it drops an empty grey bar about the width of the icon.  That happens occasionally, and if there is some particular event that precedes it, I have not yet noticed what that might be.  Nor can I include an image, as tyrying to take a screenshot makes the dropdown close up.  But it's just as described, a blank, grey area of about the icon width and I'd guess about the correct depth.  Any help anyone?